# How do I impersonate a local user that resides on a remote server

Tags: c#

I have a problem, and have scoured the web for a solution without luck. I therefor hope of a genius reads this and have useful answer to my problem.

I have a domain (“MyDomain”) and a server (“StandAloneServer”) outside “MyDomain”, but on the same physical network. On “StandAloneServer” there is a local user (“LocUsr”) that is used to run a service, and has rights to start and stop that service.

From a computer that resides inside “MyDomain”, I can access the “StandAloneServer” via RDP by using the IP address for the “StandAloneServer” and the credentials for “LocUsr”.

So far, so good - Now my problem occurs.

I would like to make a small program, that can be run on a computer that resides inside “MyDomain”, that can start and stop the service on “StandAloneServer” using the credentials of “LocUsr”. In this way a person with limited credentials and knowlagde of RDP and services can start and stop the service when needed.

All impersonation examples I can find builds on that the user to be impersonated is a member of “Mydomain” or that the program runs on the same computer as the local user – neither of this is true in my case.

How do I impersonate a local user that resides on a remote server, so that I can start and stop a service on the same remote server?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [psexec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx). This tool worked great for an application I was recently involved with for remotely restarting applications by impersonating the local user on a given pc. 
Also WMI was a tool used in the project.

[Here is an article on remote commands](https://4sysops.com/archives/three-ways-to-run-remote-windows-commands/)

Just remember that these tools are quite finicky and are unforgiving about syntax.

If you need a bit more, I would be happy to expand my answer